# Line break not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, razor, line-breaks

I am having issues with getting a line break working inside a string that is created inside a razor block.

The string gets data from a `MSSQL SERVER` but instead of printing results on a new line as I want, it prints them one after another.

I have tried:
`Enviorment.newline` using `{0}` placeholders in a `string.format()`
 `<br/>` tag by adding it as a string directly
and I have also tried `\n`.

Also I have tried replacing the `Enviorment.newline` and `\n` with `<br/>` using string.replace() - see the comment in the code below.

```
 foreach (var studentDetails in student01)
 {
    result = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", result, studentDetails.FNAME.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
    //result = result.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
 }
```

It makes no sense to me why none of these options don't work.
Any insight would be appreciated.

============================

Added screen captures of the output.
I know it shows the same name, but I am just working with dummy data at the moment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it showing the `<br />` code on the page?  I assume it's because you need to use `@Html.Raw(result)` to get any html to actually render as html.  Anytime you use the `@` to render something with RAZOR, the value gets HTML-encoded before being flushed to the output.

Comment: You don't display your printing code. You need to use `<br/>` and print the string with `MvcHtmlString.Create(result)` or `Html.Raw(result)`.

Comment: I have added images :-) Sorry about that.

Comment: Also neither solutions worked so far....

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Sorry your answer did work. If you add it as an answer I can give you more points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't display your printing code.

You need to use `<br/>` and print the string with `MvcHtmlString.Create(result)` or `Html.Raw(result)`.

Comment: Be careful with that. If the "first name" field is data-driven, it may contain untrusted input that needs to be sanitized. `Raw()` will skip the HTML encoding performed by Razor.

Comment: @Tim Absolutely! Like with any tool, you need to know how to use it properly.